# How to stop inner and outer loop using break statement

Tags: c++, objective-c, loops, for-loop, break

I have really simple code where I use `break` inside inner loop:

```
for (int it=0; it<5; it++) {
    for (int it2=0; it2<5; it2++) {
        if (it2==2) 
            break; //break here not it2, but it loop
        NSLog(@"it=%d it2=%d", it, it2);
    }
}
```

I receive an output:

```
it=0 it2=0, it=0 it2=1, 
it=1 it2=0, it=1 it2=1, 
it=2 it2=0, it=2 it2=1,
it=3 it2=0, it=3 it2=1,
it=4 it2=0, it=4 it2=1
```

I know in some programic languages there is possibility to determine on which loop break statement should affect. Is it possible to call `break` to stop outer loop (`for` with `it` variable)?

Comment: In c or c++, no. break used only for current loop

Comment: In C you cannot do it with a direct instruction (except `goto` label), but you can break from the 1st loop and set a flag to break the 2nd

Comment: For your question the way you ask it, you have two options: `goto` or a function. The more interesting question would be: what is your actual problem (the example you provide looks contrived), and in which language are you trying to solve it?

Comment: I got such problem in objective-c but every when it appears I find good solution to avoid two for loops.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really want to do this, then bite the bullet and use `goto`.

```
for (int it=0; it<5; it++) {
    for (int it2=0; it2<5; it2++) {
        if (it2==2) 
            goto end_outer_loop;
        NSLog(@"it=%d it2=%d", it, it2);
    }
}

end_outer_loop:

// more stuff here.
```

This is a legitimate `goto` (most gotos in the *downward* direction are).  In fact `break` is a special kind of "approved" goto, and because C is a minimal language you have to use an explicit goto in complex cases.

**However** as many people here have pointed out, it's better if you can use `return.`  You should not contort your program *just to avoid goto*, but in most cases it is a clue that your function is become too complex and should therefore be broken up.

Comment: `goto` shouldn't be used here. This is a text book use case for a function.

Comment: Help!  I am having a nasty flashback to the 1970s

Comment: It's good to break things into smaller functions.  But you shouldn't do that *just so you can avoid a goto*.  That really depends on whether the loop is strongly related to the calculation or not.  This is why other languages have Special language Features for this (loop labels, integer argument for break etc).

Comment: I'd also agree that for this case a `goto` is perfectly fine. Especially since the label will be very close to the `goto`.

Comment: When people have asked me for legit uses of `goto`, this is the one and only example I can cite that is in actual practical common use. I don't know why people are so averse to `goto` but totally fine with `switch` which, because of its scoping, carries the same consequences.

Comment: @tenfour exactly this. It's like everybody stops thinking just because they were told "goto is teh evul!" someday.

Comment: Thank you @AdrianRatnapala for your answer. I almost forgot that goto ever exists and now i see in some cases it's usefull.

Comment: @tenfour, the other cases I know of are `switch`-inside-a-loop and (sometimes) error exits.  But error exits are dangerous if your compiler (e.g. MSVC++) doesn't warn you about potentially undefined variables.

Comment: I agree that this is one of the few cases that goto SHOULD be used. Using a function feels like forcing a different design just for the sake of not using a goto.

Comment: +1 but OP should be warned that `goto`s are indeed considered harmful to one's reputation because of so much mindless stigma around them

Comment: @Alsk: but I only got two downvotes for this.  Fingers crossed.

Comment: Worth noting that this example is even the main feature of the [MSDN page on `goto`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b34dt9cd.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `bool flag` to serve the purpose, something like this:

```
bool flag = false;
for (int it=0; it<5; it++) {
    for (int it2=0; it2<5; it2++) {
        if (it2==2) { flag=true; break; }
        NSLog(@"it=%d it2=%d", it, it2);
    }
    if(flag) {break;}
}
```

This method shall be used only if you cannot use the `return` method as specified by others. `return` improves code-readability. This is just a workaround.

The `goto` method is also a valid one, but it is always advised not to use `goto`, just because it breaks the control flow and can cause hours of debugging if the code is large enough!

Comment: In my eyes, this is less readable and clear than using a `goto`.

Comment: I got the same idea but if statement is unnecessary. You can add condition in for statement

Comment: @Szu I agree to your proposal!

Comment: These flag variables are only mildly annoying because they are used locally; but they are a sign of the "lets add a state variable disease".  And hacked-in state variables are the worst cause I know of errors and hard-to-understand code.

Comment: @gargankit where do you get the idea that `goto` is so powerful? You cannot `goto` outside of the current function...

Answer (score 1):

In C/C++, you really don't have something like that. There are clearly some answers already, such as use `goto` or something. Personally, I don't like `goto`s and thing they kinda lead to some sloppy code (IMO).

To me you have two good options here.

1. Write the loop conditions so that they include the exit condition in both. This is the way I would personally go since I don't like the idea of using `break` or something in a loop, unless I absolutely have to. I just think it makes for a little cleaner product is all, and it's what I was taught.
2. If you do decide to keep the break, then instead of doing a single-line `if()` to control it, break it into two parts and create a "break flag" that will be set if the break condition is met. From there, either place an additional condition in your outer loop to exit if that flag is set, or have another `if()` inside the outer loop (but not inside the inner loop) that will break if that flag is set.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your loops in a function and then use `return` to return from that function.

Comment: That's a classic case of forcing a design because of language aspects. It should be the other way around

Comment: I agree that in some cases this _might_ be the way to do it. It is hard to give a definite answer without knowing the OPs actual problem. I'd argue that for almost all use-cases wrapping the iteration into a function implementing an algorithm results in a cleaner solution than using `goto`.

Comment: A good heuristic is to ask whether you can come up with a good name for that function.  Which is the same asking whether that loop does some distinct, identifiable thing.   If such a name exists, then it makes your code self-commenting.  If no such name exists, then then the in\lined text will be easier to read because it saves the reader from having to penetrate the extra layer of indirection.

Answer (score 0):

In programming using goto statement makes the logic of the program complex and tangled. In modern programming, goto statement is considered a harmful construct and a bad programming practice.

You can use it as a function and when condition occurs function exits

```
int loop(int it,int it2)
{
  for (int it=0; it<5; it++) {
    for (int it2=0; it2<5; it2++) {
        if (it2==2) return 0; //function returns here
        NSLog(@"it=%d it2=%d", it, it2);
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Breaking out of loops is one case where `goto` is considered perfectly fine. And there won't be much complexity added, as the label is really close to the jump.

Comment: I agree goto is useful , but from a professional programmers point of view it is considered to be a bad habit using goto statements. Because this could create ambiguity while reading code by others while using in complex programs. In simple ones it's ok . But for his knowledge I let him knew that it's a bad habit to use goto.

Comment: It is viewed as a bad habit everywhere except from this case. Hell, even MISRA C++ allows this. I don't see how wrapping the loops in a function is any better, it simply reduces readability in my opinion and doesn't offer any advantages since return also breaks the control flow.

Comment: @hariprasad do you, as a professional programmer, use exceptions, or `switch` statements? All these can create ambiguity for others reading the code when *misused* in complex programs. It always depends on how a feature is used, and in this specific use case `goto` will certainly *not* be seen as bad habit.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, c++ does not have that kind of break. A possibility considered abomination is using goto.
There are two acceptable solution:

1. Put this code in a separate function, and use return
2. Use a boolean flag

   bool stopFlag = false;
   for (int it=0; it<5 && !stopFlag; it++) 
   {
       for (int it2=0; it2<5; it2++) 
       {
           if (whatever) 
           {
              stopFlag=true;
              break;
          }
      }

Comment: This is one of the few cases that using goto is considered the better solution.

Comment: Veritas, I think otherwise, since in this case there are two clean alternatives. But this is a matter of taste.

Comment: Sure there are alternatives but goto is the cleaner choice. Return is really a goto in disguise and it also breaks the control flow so it doesn't offer any advantages other than providing extra work for the programmer.

Comment: Big unlike to whoever down-voted me for having different taste than his.